# Timeout on endless Http stream

Tags: c#, timeout, http-streaming

I’m writing C# client for REST service to access Http streaming API. I was supposed to open stream and receive messages that are sent by server in endless stream. On external command reading from stream should stop. HttpClient is used for implementation. Variable streamingActive is used to stop reading from stream since reader.EndOfStream will never return value true.

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout.Infinite);
    var messagesUri = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/messages/progress?sender_id=7837492342";
    var stream = httpClient.GetStreamAsync(messagesUri).Result;

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        while (streamingActive && !reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var currentLine = reader.ReadLine();
            try
            {
                var psMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PSMessage>(currentLine);
                Console.WriteLine(psMessage);
            }
            catch (JsonReaderException exc)
            {}
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine while there are messages coming from the server. If there is no new messages from server for ~300 s call reader.EndOfStream throw exception “The operation has timed out.”

```
at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.WebExceptionWrapperStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
```

Is there any way to keep stream opened (hypothetically) forever?

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to let go of the StreamReader, why not open a Stream object directly? The following is for a Universal App (using Windows.Web API)

```
HttpResponseMessage respMessage;
//note: client and request is defined elsewhere.
respMessage = client.SendRequestAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
using (var responseStream = await respMessage.Content.ReadAsInputStreamAsync())
{
   using (var fileWriteStream = await fileToStore.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
     {
        while (streamingActive && (await responseStream.ReadAsync(streamReadBuffer, bufferLength, InputStreamOptions.None)).Length > 0)
        {
          await fileWriteStream.WriteAsync(streamReadBuffer);
       }
     }
}
```

This should wait indefinitely for the `await responseStream.ReadAsync`. If you still need to cancel the opperation you can use a `Task` with `CancellationToken` approach.